# How can I call a service which has not even started?

Tags: java, android, service

What about an Android service which has not even started yet?

Can I call such a service and if so how?

Comment: Just a test, see if I get an answer. @blackcrow

Comment: I guess I have to read up on bound services vs started services.

Comment: @blackcrow, yes, I was wrong.

Comment: @blackcrow, I can not delete now because there is an answer. But I have voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "call a service"?

In the case of [started services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle); When you call `startService()`, the `onCreate()` is called if this is the first time `startService()` is called; else `onStartCommand()` is called.

In case of [bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html), when you call `bindService()`; if the service is not already running then `onCreate()` is called; else `onBind()` is called.

Comment: Also, a service can be both bound *and* be started to run indefinitely: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Answer (score 2):

You can call service via `API` only with

```
Intent i = new Intent();
startService(i);
```

But do not forget that only one copy of service can running. only one copy. and also running no service. Although more activities are able to use service, still its one copy.

Also if you implemented `onBind()` method that is support of `IPC` mechanism you are able to get Service via `bindService()` with constant `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` that means that if Service just not running, service will be start automatic. `bindService()` you can use in case when you want to communicate with service by binding.

Also for stop service use methods like `stopService()` or `unBindService()`.

Regards